# Какой алгоритм может помочь найти оптимальные параметры?

Tags: алгоритм

Существует такая задача. Есть машина у которой есть несколько параметров (например: масса, макс. скорость и тд), она должна проехать по заранее известной трассе как можно быстрее. Необходимо определить значения параметров машины.
В свое время я решил её простым перебором, наугад выставил для каждого параметра рамки (например: макс. скорость 50 - 200 км/ч с шагом 10), получилось окола миллиарда всех возможных вариантов, прогнал через cuda и через пару дней нашёл оптимальную комбинацию. Однако, это не самый лучший вариант решения, не самый точный и не самый быстрый. Подскажите, есть ли какие-то алгоритмы оптимизации для решения данной задачи?

Comment: Метод Гаусса-Зайделя. Поочередно подбираете параметр 1, фиксируете, идете по параметру 2, потом 3 и т.д., потом опять 1, 2, 3... пока не будут на очередном шаге отличия от предыдущего меньше заданной точности. Или метод градиентного спуска, Монте-Карло, наконец :) Опять же - перебором - сначала очень грубым, найдя область с решением - уже более точным, и так далее...

Comment: Чего-то условия непонятны.

Comment: Более подробно опишу, пример про машину и трассу это просто пример, который придуман по подобию реальной задачи. В оригинале есть параметры, которые очень влияют на эффективность других параметров, но сами по себе не влияют на конечный результат (например: цвет машины, который субъективно влияет на определенного пилота, но сам по себе никак не скажется эфективности машины). Пока не рассматривал предложенные выше алгоритмы, но думаю, что нужно как-то оптимизировать именно грубый перебор ибо никакой явной связи между параметрами не обнаружено.

Comment: Harry, спасибо, обязательно изучу данные алгоритмы.